# Ctrl+C and other commands working every other time in LibreOffice on 20.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, libreoffice, 20.04, clipboard, copy-and-paste

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 in English (US).

Keyboard shortcuts are working normally on the GNOME Shell and all programs but LibreOffice.

At least in Writer, Calc and Draw, commands like `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+X` are working only every other time. This means that if I copy "A" and then "B", "A" will be pasted with `Ctrl+V` and displayed on the clipboard manager (Clipboard Indicator). In the case of cut (`Ctrl+X`), "B" will disappear, but still "A" be pasted. However, if after that (i.e. for the third time) I copy or cut "C", then "C" will be pasted with `Ctrl+V` and displayed in the clipboard manager, but not "D" afterwards. And so on.

Is there any way of fixing this or should I report it as a bug? If so, where (i.e. Ubuntu or LibreOffice)?

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1852183). You could create a Launchpad account and report "this bug affects me". From various other reports, you could 1) start a Wayland session to see if this helps or 2) disable the Clipboard Indicator extension, if you have installed it.

Comment: Cheers @Jos! Disabling the extension fixed it for me. I'll have to look for a new clipboard manager now.

Comment: It's been fixed with the latest Mutter update!

Comment: @sawablo It has only been [aspirationally fixed in the latest update](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1879968). The bug is still present.

Comment: @Lexible It's worked flawlessly for me all these months!